GItHub restrict list of reviewers are allowed for a branch
Our team is working on a projects that involves multiple developers contributing to a  repository on GitHub Enterprise. We'd like to implement a stricter approval process for pull requests targeting specific release branches: all merges to release branches to only be approved by a small group of people that we can define ourselves.
If there is a way to configure GitHub to require approval from members of designated team/users? The rule should apply upon pull requests merged into specific release branches.
So far, half-way solution is so far I find out the way to make it by assigning of code-owners and setting up branch protection rule to oblige code owners to review (
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.10/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners).It requires altering of repository and create dedicated file called CODEOWNERS. We're looking for solution what keeps the repo intact.

What's the problem with adding branch protection and CODEOWNERS? What do you mean by "keeping the repo intact"? Isn't the whole point of repositories to add new code and change existing code and track these changes?

Thanks for reply. Good point. Yet , I search  solution by configuration means, the one that doesn't require creation of additional files.
The issue of CODEOWNERS is plausible merge conflicts.

Another point of concern : the file is unprotected and user can freely change the content.
Solution of CODEOWNER is pretty much depends upon good will and not regulatory

Why would CODEOWNERS be unprotected? If that file is unprotected, then your whole repository is, and you have much bigger problems. In my experience CODEOWNERS doesn't change a lot, especially if you use an email group alias as the owners. Even if it gets changed between branches, it's usually a small file and merge conflicts can be resolved easily. I have the gut feeling you're not fully understanding the idea here. If you're on github, the .github directory is where a lot of the configuration lives. This is a good thing, it keeps stuff in the repository / in one place.

Thanks for pointing out.
Developers able to temper CODEOWNERS at will. We'd rather looking a way to apply strict limits in terms of ability to assign reviewers. The use case is to protect release branches by assigning review upon dedicated team.  I just was wondering if there is suitable  feature of GitHub server itself.

At this point it sounds like you are trying to solve a people problem with a technical solution.

:) Good point, legit remark, thanks. I'm going to stick with CODEOWNERS .
